# QGLWidget not receiving calls to resizeGL after initialization

Tags: c++, qt, qglwidget

I am having what appears to be the same problem as asked in this (unanswered) question: [Qt resizeGL problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656905/qt-resizegl-problem)

I am testing a new `QGLWidget` for a larger application. The `resizeGL` method is wired up to change the `glViewport` and repaint the OpenGL view. My QGLWidget is not part of a layout and is simply being created displayed as follows:

```
boost::shared_ptr<StandardCustomWidgetBuilder>
        builder(new StandardCustomWidgetBuilder());
WaterfallDirector<StandardCustomWidgetBuilder, DataSource> director(builder);
director.construct();
std::unique_ptr<CustomWidget> widget = builder->getWidget();
widget->show();
```

On my computer, this defaults to creating a 640x480 window and calls `resizeGL` upon initialization. Whenever I resize the window, `resizeGL` is never called.

In my attempts to remedy this I have attempted creating a separate `QWidget` that has a `QVBoxLayout` containing only the `CustomWidget`. This created a very small window, so I fixed my `sizeHint` and `sizePolicy` for `CustomWidget`, though this still had no affect on having `resizeGL` called. At this point I'm not sure precisely how to proceed.

Comment: Do you overload `QGLWidget::resizeEvent()`?  Implement it and see if you are handling the resize events.

Comment: I do not overload that. I added `virtual void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent * event)` to my protected methods and put a breakpoint inside of it and it was never hit.

Comment: Best I can do at this point is to say, create a regular widget as similar to your QGLWidget and see if you catch its resize events.  That might help you zero in on the problem.  Also it may be a question of widget's parent, which I'm assuming is NULL.  That should be ok, but if you find that making it a child of a QWidget solves the problem, that could help too.

Comment: I started down the path of creating a wrapper `QWidget` that would forward resize events to the `QGLWidget` but that resulted in a grayed out widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved my problem with some help from my co-worker. As it turns out, I had implemented the `event` method and forgot to call the `QGLWidget::event` method inside it. The widget now correctly resizes.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't done so already, I would suggest checking the [size hints and size policies](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qwidget.html#size-hints-and-size-policies) of all widgets concerned.

For example, the following will make sure your widget uses available space when the window grows:

```
widget->setSizePolcy( QSizePolicy::MinimumExpanding,
                      QSizePolicy::MinimumExpanding );
```

I don't think that the default size policy for QGLWidget makes it want to expand, so I'm thinking it's just possible that this needs changing.

Comment: The QGLWidget still seems to ignore the expanding part of the size policy.